# My Quicksort doesn't work with negative numbers (Common Lisp)

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp, quicksort, negative-number

The function works fine with only positive number. Works sometimes with negative but most of the time show this error "The value -1 is not of type UNSIGNED-BYTE".

```
(defun OrdRapido (lista inf sup)
  (let ((pivote (nth sup lista)) (i (1- inf)) (j sup) (aux))
    (unless (>= inf sup)
        (loop (when (>= i j) (return))
          (loop (setf i (1+ i)) (when (>= (nth i lista) pivote) (return)))
          (loop (setf j (1- j)) (when (<= (nth j lista) pivote) (return)))
          (when (< i j)
            (setf aux (nth i lista))
            (setf (nth i lista) (nth j lista))
            (setf (nth j lista) aux)))  
        (setf aux (nth i lista))
        (setf (nth i lista) (nth sup lista))
        (setf (nth sup lista) aux) 
        (OrdRapido lista inf (1- i))
        (OrdRapido lista (1+ i) sup)) 
    lista))
```

For example:

```
(setq lista2 '(-5 3 7 6 2 1 -4 100 5 80 96 14 2 3 1 0 0 789 -1 3))
(OrdRapido lista2 0 (1- (length lista2)))

CL-USER> 
(-5 3 7 6 2 1 -4 100 5 80 96 14 2 3 1 0 0 789 -1 3)
CL-USER> 
(-5 -4 -1 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 5 6 7 14 80 96 100 789)
```

But doesn't work with this, and I only add the - to 80

```
'(-5 3 7 6 2 1 -4 100 5 -80 96 14 2 3 1 0 0 789 -1 3)
```

Thanks

Corrected version (random pivot added), I know there are better ways, It's just an exercise the profesor left

```
 (defun OrdRapido (lista inf sup)
  (let ((pivote (nth (random (1+ sup)) lista)) (i inf) (j sup) (aux))
    (unless (>= inf sup)
        (loop (when (> i j) (return))
          (loop (when (<= (nth i lista) pivote) (return)) (setf i (1+ i)))
          (loop (when (>= (nth j lista) pivote) (return)) (setf j (1- j)))
          (when (<= i j)
            (setf aux (nth i lista))
            (setf (nth i lista) (nth j lista))
            (setf (nth j lista) aux)
            (setf i (1+ i))
            (setf j (1- j))))  
        (OrdRapido lista inf j)
        (OrdRapido lista i sup)) 
    lista))
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with negative numbers, try `'(2 1)`.

Comment: whether these "other ways" shown in the answers, i.e. recursive flattened-tree variants, are "better", is open to debate. Your code looks like true quicksort, partitioning in-place. You can improve it by choosing pivot randomly, to prevent the drastic slowdown on ordered input.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just added the random pivot :)

Comment: Regardless of whether this is "true" quicksort or not... your code has a disastrous asymptotic complexity. You should either rewrite it to use arrays, or do it entirely differently with lists. What you did here is beyond quadratic time.

Comment: Basically, think of it this way: if you are using `nth` with a constant less then, say, 8, you are good. But if not, you are doing things the wrong way. But it is best to never use it / only for debugging.

Comment: The assignment was "make a function that orders a list with quicksort". I only need to show the code, order a few short lists and that's all. I'm not using the code later, it's just a list of exercises from my professor. But thanks for the info.

Comment: @wvxvw ``(defmacro ith (i a) `(elt ,a ,i))``, replace `nth` with `ith` throughout, and voila! - the code is good for arrays too. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to return the -1th element of a list which won't work. nth returns the nth element of the list so (nth 0 '(1 2 3)) will return 1. But at some point in your code it calls (nth -1 (-5 -80 -4 -1 0 0 ...)) and boom!

Other notes about your code:

- Putting the closing ) on a seperate line is not good lisp style and makes your code harder to read. Lisp code is made of lists, the parens are not really like the curly braces of other languages.
- Use an editor that supports your language. I recommend Vim with Slim or Emacs with slime. If you use emacs with slime [this video may help you get started](http://youtu.be/VnWVu8VVDbI).
- Dont use camel casing in your names. All symbols are upcased in common lisp when they are interned so **'HelloThere** is *EXACTLY the same symbol* as **'hellothere** or **'HELLOTHERE**

Also please look [at the rosettacode page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Common_Lisp) for quicksort to see how to do it in common-lisp (and lots of other languages).

```
;; Here is a functional version for example.
(defun quicksort (list &aux (pivot (car list)) )
  (if (rest list)
      (concatenate 'list 
             (quicksort (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (< x pivot)) list))
             (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (= x pivot)) list)
             (quicksort (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (> x pivot)) list)))
      list))
```

If you are not used to reading lambdas then here is the same code as above but with the lambdas made into local functions so the code reads a little more like english.

```
(defun quicksort (list &aux (pivot (car list)))
  (labels ((less-than-pivot (x) (< x pivot))
           (greater-than-pivot (x) (> x pivot))
           (equal-to-pivot (x) (= x pivot)))
    (if (rest list)
        (concatenate 'list 
                     (quicksort (remove-if-not #'less-than-pivot list))
                     (remove-if-not #'equal-to-pivot list)
                     (quicksort (remove-if-not #'greater-than-pivot list)))
        list)))
```

The second version is a little less tidy in my mind. In both of these examples you can see how the recursive approach lets you think about how to do just one step and then by calling itself you apply the solution for one step to get the solution to the entire problem

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll stop putting ) in other lines, I'm new with Lisp, I'm not used to it yet. I know Hello and HELLO are the same, I just liked it. I know there are better ways to do quicksort  with lisp but since I'm just starting to practicing I wanted to implement the "classic" way. I found the error in the code, I just didn't know what the error means, thanks again :)

Comment: except that it is not a "true" quicksort (i.e. doesn't do the in-place array partitioning which was what Hoare considered to be his real invention - or so the story goes). This recursive code builds a ternary tree, *already flattened*. so it is a *treesort* (which builds a tree, and then flattens it). (it's not my idea of course; there's [a reddit thread about it](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2h0j2/real_quicksort_in_haskell), based on a Haskell equivalent).

Comment: Well bugger that'll teach me for copy and paste without checking. I'll fix this when I have time

Comment: @Baggers please do not remove anything. :)

Comment: Ok I'm just going to leave this as-is, there is good discussion everywhere on why this isn't real quicksort and good links to help people on the track to implementing the real one. Thanks to everyone for the excellent input

Answer (score 1):

Just because your initial idea was to do this with `loop`. Here's how you might've done it:

```
(defun quicksort (list)
  (if (cdr list)
      (loop :with pivot := (car list)
         :for element :in list
         :if (< element pivot) :collect element :into a
         :else :if (= element pivot) :collect element :into b
         :else :collect element :into c
         :finally (return (nconc (quicksort a) b (quicksort c)))) list))
```

Comment: again, this is not Quicksort

Comment: @RainerJoswig but if you follow the description exactly - you cannot do it with lists, because you would need random access. So what's the point arguing? IMO, this is the closest you can get with lists.

Comment: it's not quicksort, but slowsort with lists.

Comment: @RainerJoswig not surprisingly no one uses Quicksort to sort lists. So, what's the point arguing, if this isn't a practical algorithm anyway?

Comment: Your example uses lists and claims it is quicksort, which it isn't.

Comment: @RainerJoswig you are welcome to re-read my first comment in this answer, particularly the part that says "this is the closest you can get with lists". Pay special attention to the word "closest". In case you didn't notice it before, it is not the same as "exact".

Comment: It does not look very close, since it is a slow and space wasting sort. Copy the list into an array, do a quicksort and update the original list would be better.

Comment: @RainerJoswig that would be a sort that operates on arrays... as in, not a quicksort that operates on lists. Which is pointless if you want it to operate on lists. This sorting function is slow / inefficient? - read my second reply: no one will ever use quicksort with lists. Is OP writing his/er code to do high-perf. real-time number crunching? - well, my guess is this is an assignment / attempt at self-educating, where the priorities are different. OP wanted something that's close to Quicksort and works on lists - here it is. If OP wanted it to work on arrays, that would be a different story.

Comment: @wvxvw you're right of course about the high-performance stuff; but as an assignment, it probably required the code to be written as if it were an array based quicksort. :) but your code is a valid addition to the whole picture, provides a counterpoint, so please don't remove it. :)

Comment: @RainerJoswig treesort isn't _that_ bad, :) it's still *n log n* average case (or even, worst case, with randomized pivot). Of course for lists, mergesort is probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Barring compiler tricks, NTH takes O(i) time to access the ith element of a list, because it has to walk across every element of the list up to that point. This means that merely accessing every element of a list by using NTH will take O(n^2) time. Since quicksort is supposed to execute in O(nlgn) time, it is necessary to make a slight alteration.

By holding on to the remaining tail while you walk the list and accessing through that tail instead of using NTH, you can quicksort a list. It is also necessary to only walk the list in the forward direction because lisp lists are singly linked.

```
(defun simple-list-partition (list end)
  "Reorder list until end such that all values less than the first value in the
  list are placed left of it and all greater placed to its right; return the new
  index of the first value and the tail of the list starting with that value as
  multiple values."
  (loop for walk-cons on (cdr list)
        for walk-value = (car walk-cons)
        for walk-index from 1
        with pivot-value = (car list)
        with rotate-cons = list
        with rotate-index = 0
        while (<= walk-index end)
        when (< walk-value pivot-value)
        do (progn (setq rotate-cons (cdr rotate-cons)
                        rotate-index (+ 1 rotate-index))
                  (rotatef (car rotate-cons) (car walk-cons)))
        finally (progn (rotatef (car list) (car rotate-cons))
                       (return (values rotate-index rotate-cons)))))

(defun quicksort (list)
  "Quicksort for lists."
  (labels ((quicksort% (l  max)
             (when (and (plusp max) (cdr l))
               (multiple-value-bind (index tail)
                   (simple-list-partition l max)
                 (quicksort% l (1- index))
                 (quicksort% (cdr tail) (- max index 1))))))
    (quicksort% list (1- (length list)))
    list))
```

For simplicity the above doesn't protect against poor performance on lists that are either presorted or of equal elements.